# What's the difference between grep \\$ and grep \\\$?

Tags: shell, unix, grep

When I type `grep \\\$` shell escapes both `\` and `$` and transforms it to `\$` and sends to grep, which then finds all the lines with dollar sign `$`. That's fine!

When I type `grep \\$` the result is the same and I don't really know why. The first backslash should escape the second one, but then `$` is not escaped and shell should replace it with an empty string? grep should receive `\` and report an error but instead everything works as in first example for some reason..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UNIX shells, `$x` is replaced by the value of the shell variable `x` but when there is nothing following the `$`, no substitution is performed. You can test this with `echo`:

```
> echo $
$
> echo $x

>
```

Your two grep arguments are passed into grep as exactly the same regular expression.

```
> echo \\\$
\$
> echo \\$
\$
>
```

Comment: So in shell there's no point of escaping the single dollar sign $ ? But I have to escape $$, because it will search for a shell variable named $? OK, thank you!

Comment: Well `$$` is special, it expands to the process ID of the shell, but yes. As for "no point", consistency is not a bad thing.